# Multiple conditions bulk update in SQL & PHP

Tags: php, sql

If I want to update a column value base on a condition I can just use the below query for a simpel +1 -1 case (translate into proper PHP call or ORM equivalent, of course):

```
UPDATE articles SET STATUS = 0 WHERE STATUS  = 1;
```

But now the issue is that I want, based on the original the `status`, infer a new value of `status` from a dictionary. Assuming that the dictionary is something like this:

```
dict['1']='3'
dict['12']='2'
dict['6']='2'
```

There is no relationship between key-value pair. The `dict` is a PHP dictionary object, that's what I meant by "`in memory dictionary`".

How to write this query?

**Edit: Question edit. I didn't frame the question properly...  sorry!**

Comment: What if status already is at it's max-value?

Comment: I have update the question to make it reflective of my situation here.

Comment: If it's an in-memory dictionary, where are you performing the updates from? An application of some kind? Is there any way to write the dictionary out to a table in the database, and then update it using the query in my answer?

Comment: What do you mean that there is 'no relationship between key value pair'. They are related as the key maps to the value. I guess you were trying to say that there is no simple formula mapping them.

Comment: WTF, I thought you accepted an answer on this? but now it has been edited _into_ another question.  You should ask a new question, now someone has downvoted my answer to the original question, which does not apply to this new question now. thanks!

Comment: @KM... sorry for that, maybe you can update the answer?

Comment: no, I'd just be duplicating one of the other answers, I'll just up vote the one I think is correct now...

Answer (score 4):

If you have a small number of mappings then you could use a `case` statement.

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE articles
SET status = 
       case 
          when status=1 then 3 
          when status=12 or status=6 then 2 
          else status --leave it unchanged if it doesn't match a case
       end

--COMMIT OR ROLLBACK
```

Otherwise take the mapping table approach as suggested by rwmnau

Comment: This was my initial thought, but I couldn't tell how big the table was from his example. If it's a one-time thing and the table is a manageable size, this might be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use  subquery:

```
UPDATE articles AR SET status = (SELECT value FROM dict WHERE key = AR.status)
```

Of course, I assume that you have dictionary stored in your database.

Comment: Good try, but that dict is not a database table-- it's an memory-dictionary

Comment: If it was a table, this could be done with a join instead of a sub-query, which is significantly less taxing on the server.

Comment: @rwmnau: Good point ;)

@Ngu Soon Hui: what do you mean by memory-dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
UPDATE articles
   SET status = n.new
  FROM articles a
  JOIN NewStatus n
    ON a.status = n.status
```

That way, you'd have a second table called "NewStatus" that had two columns - one called "status" with your existing status, and one called "New" that had the status you wanted it to update to. Join to that table, do your update, and that should solve it. Also, if there are any statuses you don't want to update, just don't include them in your NewStatus table - then they'll be skipped in the update statement.

It looks like the question's been modified, so if I'm missing the point, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is unclear and you appear to be mixing code and SQL you could do something like this (pseudo Java):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBulder();

for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : codes.entrySet) {

    sb.append(
      String.format("UPDATE articles SET Status=%s WHERE Status=%s\n", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey() 
       );

}

String sqlToExecute = sb.toString();
System.out.println(sqlToExecute);
```

This will give you the SQL to execute to make the changes. If this code is going to be more of a one off then get rid of the String formatting and use prepared statements instead.